# multiple of number upto 100 times

Tags: java

I'm triying to find common multiples of two numbers up to 100 times, but actually it will only prints 5 to 10 common multiples.

Please give me suggestion on this of how to print 100 common factors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintMultipleOfNo {

    public static void test(int x,int y)
    {
        int n=100;
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0&&y%i==0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            continue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x,y;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();
        PrintMultipleOfNo.test(x,y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is printing out all common factors up to 100. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Calculate the `lcm` and multiply it with all numbers in the range `[1, 100]`.

Comment: You should provide some examples of input + output that doesn't match your expectations, and a description of exactly what you don't like about it.

Comment: You also declare and int n that you never use!

Comment: That `continue` statement looks superfluous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LCM of two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176749/lcm-of-two-numbers)

Comment: Did you want common **multiples** or common **factors**?  Your question says both, and the two things are virtually exact opposites.  BTW it looks like the code is printing common _factors_ between the values of 1 and 100.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare `int n=100;` and use `continue;`
Also if you want get 100 answers, you must increase `i` only if your if-block is true.

UPD: And for preventing infinite loop we can add another if-block.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintMultipleOfNo {

    public static void test(int x, int y)
    {
        for(int i = 1, n = 0; n < 100; i++)
        {
            if(x%i == 0 && y%i == 0)
            {
               System.out.println(i);
               n++;
            }

            if (i > x || i > y)
               break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        PrintMultipleOfNo.test(x,y);
    }
}
```